# How to insert datalist value into another databse tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Assumes that i have two tables,**table 1** and **table 2**. **Table 1** contains information such as Pictures, Name and Price. **Table 2** contains information about order list,Table Number,Quantity and Price.

If I used **DataList** to display the data from **table 1**, and added a quantity(name) drop down list, a Table Number(name) Drop Downlist and a Submit button, how can i add the selected data to **Table 2**?

*I'm trying to create an ordering menu using ASP.net, what it does was actually shows the food menu from table 1 using DataList and the waiter submit the quantity,Table Number and Food Name to the kitchen side (kitchen.aspx) which has a gridview with Order list,Quantity and Table Number on it.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I think what you are facing is database design problem. Why would you save table 1 data into table 2 data !! you should only save the ID from table 1. But first you have to add column table1ID to add it.

Comment: what have you tried? do you have some sample code/sql? this should be a simple insert query, which adds the id from table 1 into table 2 along with the quantity and any other order specific details.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: i've edited the question~i just need some idea on how to insert data from the datalist to the kitchen side table..